# Android Mask two Bitmap clear border

Tags: android, bitmap, masking

I'm using the mask a bitmap with another. The operation succeeds well, unfortunately the result of masking seen a slight black border, as you can see in the image:

[image]

How do I remove this border? in the source image is not there.

I'll post the code I'm using:

```
public Bitmap mask(Bitmap source) {
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(getMask(), 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    return targetBitmap;        
}
```

where getMask () returns the Bitmap that represents the figure of the Puzzle.
I hope to receive your help, thank you all

Sorry for my english :-)

UPDATE:

the black border is what I point out in this picture:

[image]

UPDATE:

place the sequence of transformation. The third image would be identical to the first but without color. The problem is the black edge of the puzzle.
I hope to be more clear:

[image]

Comment: What is that black border you mention? What are the inputs that generate that image?

Comment: It would be best if you posted all images you using, and your expected result.

Comment: I've added new information and pictures, no one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The way I draw images with mask is kind of the other way around from what you do.

```
public Bitmap mask(Bitmap source) {
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    // paint.setAntiAlias(true); // you've already set this in the constructor
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(getMask(), 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
    // paint.setXfermode(null); // no need for this
    return targetBitmap;        
}
```

Note that PorterDuff.Mode is set to SRC_IN (not DST_in) and that the mask is drawn first and then the image on top of that mask. With this approach you can also draw the previous source as the base mask, add the new (puzzle) mask and then draw the final source/image on top of that with SRC_IN paint to add new puzzle pieces each time.
If that doesn't solve the black border, check that your mask doesn't have feathered (transparent) edges that might be causing these problems.

Also, ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG doesn't do anything on textures. If you want smoothly scaled textures use paint.setFilterBitmap(true);